# How do I download an entire webpage (with images) on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Is there a way to download an entire webpage for offline viewing with the iPhone SDK? I can use NSString with the contents of the URL, but that would just give me the HTML and no images. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popular open source library `ASIHTTPRequest` has a class that will do just this for you: download all HTML, images, and other resources associated with the page you're requesting.

It's called `ASIWebPageRequest`, and you can read the documentation and download it from here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

Comment: thank you sir and sorry for the asking the same question I had totally forgot about this question

Comment: This open source library is outdated and not supported anymore. Is there an alternative for iOS 7?