# UIWebView caching of local HTML string

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

In my application, I have an HTML string that's stored locally, that I load into a UIWebView for display.

This HTML string has references to images that are online. Does anyone know of a way to cache the images when loaded, so that when offline, the UIWebView can load with the images ?

I'm loading the UIWebView with "loadHTMLString" not "loadURLRequest"

Thanks

Comment: Try to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826820/uiwebview-webpage-caching-for-offline-viewing

Comment: Thanks, although my UIWebView is being loaded from a local string, not a URLRequest, I guess the question is, is there a way to load the string *into* a request ?

Comment: There are some outer links. I hope, this can help you: http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol/