# caching multiple html pages for mobile web app

Tags: java, javascript, ios, html, caching

I was wondering if there is a way to cache multiple `html` pages with their individual content.

The current structure I have for my **web app** is that i have a `index.html` file which needs to be cached. Within this there are pictures and videos that need to be cached.

These pictures then linked to another `html` file with its own images and video which all need to be cached.

I already know all the file locations of the files i want to cache e.g. **images/about/images.jpg
images/page/render.jpg
images/locations/place.jpg**

The final end product will be distributed to the iOS app store and Android market. As far as I am aware the way to cache is by using the `HTML5` cache manifest and reading through the docs it seems that i am unable to do this from the single `index.html` rather have to click on each page before it can be cached.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you are going to add those HTML files and corresponding resources into the application within the app or you wish to cache them once it is loaded into the UIWebview.

Comment: currently the way the application is set up is that the separate pages can be edited by the client as teh UIWebView is simply loading the html page. The client wishes to have a 'offline mode'

the app itself that is going to be distributed to the appstore is just going to be the UIWebView linking to the clients login area, once the user has logged in they then view the pages that are just for them - but there will be say 20 pages just for the user. 

I want to cache these files and their content before they have been viewed through the UIWebView.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826820/uiwebview-webpage-caching-for-offline-viewing

Comment: Thanks, would i have to include this App build? Is there a similar solution for the Andriod?

Comment: Am not sure about the solution for android. Kindly upvote if you have found the answer you have been searching for.